# Generate random numbers and insert into textfield

Tags: c#, asp.net

My objective is to generate random numbers and insert into 4 different textfields.

My Code Behind

```
protected void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = GenerateNumber().ToString();
    TextBox2.Text = GenerateNumber().ToString();
    TextBox3.Text = GenerateNumber().ToString();
    TextBox4.Text = GenerateNumber().ToString();
}

private int GenerateNumber()
{
    int i = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();
    i = rand.Next(0, 100);

    return i;
}
```

But it then generates 4 same numbers in 4 textfields.

[image]

I want to have different numbers in different textfields without repeating.

Comment: move `Random` from the method: `private static Random rand = new Random();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways in which you can generate different numbers keeping your code intact. Like, for example:

Passing an extra parameter in your method `GenerateNumber()`,

```
protected void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = GenerateNumber(36).ToString();
    TextBox2.Text = GenerateNumber(21).ToString();
    TextBox3.Text = GenerateNumber(77).ToString();
    TextBox4.Text = GenerateNumber(9).ToString();
}

private int GenerateNumber(int a)
{
    int i = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();
    i = rand.Next(a, 100);
    return i;
}
```

or, as @[Dmitry Bychenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319407/dmitry-bychenko) told to create a static object of the `Random` class outside the `GenerateNumber()` method:

```
private static Random rand = new Random();
private int GenerateNumber()
{
    int i = 0;
    i = rand.Next(0, 100);
    return i;            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the rand out of the methods,so you won't create a new one every time you call your method.One way is to have it as a property on the class.

```
Random rand = new Random();
protected void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = GenerateNumber().ToString();
    TextBox2.Text = GenerateNumber().ToString();
    TextBox3.Text = GenerateNumber().ToString();
    TextBox4.Text = GenerateNumber().ToString();
}

private int GenerateNumber()
{
    int i = 0;
    i = rand.Next(0, 100);
    return i;
}
```

The other is to pass it as a parameter

```
private int GenerateNumber(Random rand)
{
    int i = 0;
    i = rand.Next(0, 100);
    return i;
}
```

And to be honest I don't know why you have a method for something that already has a method.

```
protected void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    TextBox1.Text = rand.Next(0, 100).ToString();
    TextBox2.Text = rand.Next(0, 100).ToString();
    TextBox3.Text = rand.Next(0, 100).ToString();
    TextBox4.Text = rand.Next(0, 100).ToString();
}
```